# How can I detect whether a browser supports CSS3 blur?

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

I'm trying to write something in JS that allows me to tell whether a user's browser supports CSS3 `blur`, and display (or not display) an element as necessary. It doesn't look like [Modernizr supports it](http://www.browserleaks.com/modernizr), and I really couldn't figure out another way to check this. How can I do this?

Comment: https://raw.github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/master/feature-detects/css/filters.js

Comment: I saw, but that's the filter property, which most browsers support…

Comment: Currently, only webkit browsers support the `filter` property.

Comment: According to jQuery.support.filter…Firefox supports it…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`blur`](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#blurltlengthgt) is actually a value of the CSS [`filter`](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterProperty) property, and not a CSS property within itself.

To check for support of the CSS3 `filter` property with modernizr, you can simply use the `Modernizr.cssfilters` value.

Comment: So there's no real way to detect whether it supports blur specifically?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. In Modernizr terms, supporting the `filter` property means supporting all its values according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterProperty). So by definition and spec, `Modernizr.cssfilters` specifically detects support for the `blur` function.

Comment: Okay…I will try that out. Sounds like it'll work, so I accepted it. Thanks!